# Filter and data have missing dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I have one issue with my code where I need to filter though "id" and this is the error that I get " React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'data' and 'filterData'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.

```
 useEffect(() => {
   if (content === "") {
     setFilterData(data); 
     return;
   }

   const filteredData = filterData.filter((item) => item.Id === content);
   setFilterData(filteredData);
 }, [content]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the dependency for `data` and `filterData`

```
  useEffect(() => {
   if (content === "") {
     setFilterData(data); 
     return;
   }

   const filteredData = filterData.filter((item) => item.Id === content);
   setFilterData(filteredData);
 }, [content, filterData, data]);
```

You can use the below code. This is the better implementation.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if(data){
   const filteredData = content === "" ? data : data.filter((item) => item.Id === content);
   setFilterData(filteredData);
   }
 }, [content, data]);
```

Comment: that means, filterData is undefined. you can handle it as const filteredData = filterData?.filter((item) => item.Id === content);

Answer (score 1):

You only declared `content` as dependency in your `useEffect` block, but you're actually using `data` (which is a prop) and `filterData` (which is coming from `useState()`) as well.

These are dependencies and the error message is saying you need to declare them too (meaning your `useEffect` block will be executed every time one of its dependencies changes) or to remove depencencies at all (meaning your `useEffect` block will be executed only once):

```
 useEffect(() => {
       if (content === "") {
         setFilterData(data); 
         return;
       }
    
       const filteredData = filterData.filter((item) => item.Id === content);
       setFilterData(filteredData);
     }, 
     [content, data, filterData] // or [] for no depencencies
 );
```